# Can you achieve the following behavior by using Hero widget alone?

Tags: flutter

Anyone knows how to resolve this issue... or implement the behavior I want.
So on page 1, I have 8 images item, each item has its own hero tag.  On page 2, it's a tab view with all identical 8 images URL, each image with matching hero tag with page 1. As you can see in the [Demo Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zE56-lDkchiA6Rdf68x1ysaqONH4H3ad/view?usp=sharing), if I change the currentIndex on the page2, it won't show the hero animation when I pop page 2 of the stack...
so I want it to show the hero animation back to the right image on page 1, even when I change the index on page 2... Is that possible with the Hero widget. or do I need to do it with something else?

Page 1 code snippet where I implemented the hero widget:

```
 `Hero(
     tag: '$heroTag${ibChoice.url!}',
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            child: itemController.isLocalFile
                ? Image.file(
                    File(ibChoice.url!),
                    height: IbConfig.kPicHeight,
                    width: IbConfig.kPicHeight,
                  )
                : CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl: ibChoice.url!,
                    height: IbConfig.kPicHeight,
                    width: IbConfig.kPicHeight,
                  ),
          ),
        ),`
   onDoubleTap: () {
      /// show image preview
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          PageRouteBuilder(
              opaque: false,
              barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
              barrierDismissible: true,
              pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) => IbMediaViewer(
                  urls: itemController.rxIbQuestion.value.choices
                      .map((e) => e.url!)
                      .toList(),
                  currentIndex: itemController.rxIbQuestion.value.choices
                      .map((e) => e.url!)
                      .toList()
                      .indexWhere((element) => ibChoice.url! == element),
                  heroTag: heroTag,
                  isLocal: itemController.isLocalFile)));
    },
```

Page2(IbMediaViewer) code snippet:

```
Stack(
  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
  children: [
    TabBarView(
        controller: controller,
        children: widget.urls.map((e) {
          Widget img = const SizedBox();
          if (widget.isLocal) {
            img = Image.file(
              File(e),
            );
          } else {
            img = CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: e);
          }

          return Hero(
            tag: '${widget.heroTag}$e',
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Get.back();
              },
              child: InteractiveViewer(
                boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: img,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }).toList()),
    Positioned(
        bottom: 16,
        child: Center(
          child: TabPageSelector(
            controller: controller,
          ),
        ))
  ],
);
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that will reproduce the issue?

Comment: you can use bolean value. to manage  back navigation when user come to page set value true after animation set it to false

Comment: @FlutterDev can you be more specific? is there a specific boolean I can set for the hero widget?